# Single Population Model with Harvesting: Mathematical Modelling

Tags: mathematical-modeling, applications

I'm hoping someone can just check if my solution is correct and if I understand the problem that is being asked. If any part of it is wrong or you don't understand me let me know. Thanks very much for your time.

> In a fish farm, fish are harvested at a constant rate of $2100 \,\dfrac{\text{fish}}{\text{week}}$. The per-capita birth rate for the fish is $0.7 \, \dfrac{\text{fish}}{\text{day}}$, and the per-capita death rate for the fish is $0.2\,\dfrac{\text{fish}}{\text{day}}.$
>
> (a) Write down the word equation for the fish population $F(t)$ in the farm.

{Rate of change of population of fish} = {Birth rate} - {Death rate} - {Rate of fish harvested}.

> (b) Write the differential rate equation for the number of fish.

We need to be careful here because the per-capita rate is measured *per day* and the harvesting rate is measured *per week*. Putting our word equation into mathematics we have

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{dF}{dt} & = 4.9F \, \dfrac{\text{1}}{\text{week}}-1.4F \, \dfrac{\text{1}}{\text{week}}-2100 \, \dfrac{\text{1}}{\text{week}} \\
               & = 3.5F -2100
\end{align}$$

> (c) Solve the differential rate equation to obtain the formula for the fish population $F(t)$ at any time $t$ in terms of the initial fish population $F_0$.

Solve this using separation of variables. I'm going to skip this and just show you my general solution.

$$F(t)= \dfrac{Ce^{3.5t}+2100}{3.5} $$

where $C$ is my constant of integration and $C=e^{c_1 t}$.

The question says that we can use any time $t$. Lets $F(0) = F_0$ be our initial fish population. Now are particular solution can be found by using this initial condition.

$$\begin{align}
F(0)= F_0 & = \dfrac{C+2100}{3.5} \\
C & = 3.5F_0 -2100
\end{align}$$

With our particular solution being

$$F(t) = (F_0 -600)e^{3.5t} +600$$

it's also in terms of out initial population $F_0$

> (d) Find the equilibrium solution $F_e$

The equilibrium solution is when the rate of change of the population does not change. When $\dot{F}(t)=0$.

$$\dfrac{dF}{dt}= 3.5F -2100$$

Let $F=F_e$ and $\dfrac{dF}{dt}=0$

$$F_e = 600$$

> (e) Find the long-term solution with dependence on $F_0$. What happens when the initial fish population $F_0$ is equal to the equilibrium solution $F_e$?

The long-term solution examines the behaviour of the population as $t\rightarrow \infty.$

$$ F(t) = (F_0 -600)e^{3.5t} +600$$
**I:** When $F_0<600$ the term inside $(F_0-600)$ gets increasing *smaller* as $t\rightarrow \infty$. In fact $F(t)\rightarrow -\infty$ and the population will become extinct.

**II:** When $F_0>600$ the term inside $(F_0-600)$ gets increasing *bigger* as $t\rightarrow \infty$. The population will explode and $F(t) \rightarrow +\infty$.

**III:** When $F_0 = F_e = 600$ the term inside $(F_0-600)$  goes to zero, $F(t) = 600$ and stays constant.  It's also important to note that when the initial population is at equilibrium it will stay at equilibrium.

> (f)Find the time interval on which $F(t) \ge 0$ with dependence on $F_0$.

This is the part that I'm kind of struggling on. We have $F(t)$ so I'm going to find for what value of $t$ is $F(t) = 0$.

$$\begin{align}
(F_0-600)e^{3.5t}+2100 & = 0 \\
 (F_0-600e^3.5t       & = -2100 \\
              e^{3.5t} & = \dfrac{-2100}{F_0 -600} \\
                     t & = \dfrac{\ln{\Bigg(\dfrac{-2100}{F_0 -600}\Bigg)}}{3.5}
\end{align}$$

This is  the value of $t$ when $F(t)=0$. Also it's important that $F_0 \ne F_e$. We know that for $F_0>F_e$ our population $F(t)>0$ But in my above expression for $t$. we cannot have $F_0>F_e$ because it's not real. So does that mean that $F(t) =0$ when $F_0<F_e$?

I'm starting to confuse myself with part (f). A bit of help would be much appreciated. Thanks